# Nodejs - Graphic Magic or ImageMagic - overlay as Photoshop

Tags: node.js, image, imagemagick, gm

Is it possible to compose an image with gm as we do it with photoshop. Here is a picture what I mean: [image]

What I am using now is multibly, but it doesn't provide the same effect as overlay so I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this.

Here is my code with gm:

```
            gm()
            .command("composite")
            .in('-compose', 'Multiply')
            .in( 'output.jpg' )
            .in( 'background.jpg')
            .write( 'output.jpg', function (err) {
              if (!err) 
                console.log(' hooray! ');
              else
                console.log(err);
            });
```

If it's not possible with gm. I don't mind to use ImageMagic if it's going to provide that functionality. Thank you in advanced for any suggestions.

Comment: Maybe use `'-compose','overlay'`

Comment: Failing that, please provide the 2 starting images you want to overlay and also an image showing the final result.

Comment: That was what I looking for. This is strange that this option is not in their documentation: http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-compose

Comment: Mmm, not sure what's up with the `GraphicsMagick` documentation, but in `ImageMagick` you can get a list of the `compose` modes with `identify -list compose`.